# Fork(), wait for all child process to finish vs wait for one child to finish

Tags: c, fork, parent-child, wait

I don't understand as to where should I use the wait(NULL) or while(pid = wait(&status))>0). I am very confused and I get weird results please help!.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   pid_t childpid = 0; 
   int i, n;

   if (argc != 2){   /* check for valid number of command-line arguments */ 
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s processes\n", argv[0]);
      return 1; 
   }     
   n = atoi(argv[1]);  
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
      if ((childpid = fork()) <= 0)
         break;

   fprintf(stderr, "i:%d  process ID:%ld  parent ID:%ld  child ID:%ld\n",
           i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid(), (long)childpid);
   return 0; 
}
```

1. How would you modify this code so that the original process prints out its information after all children have exited?
2. How would you modify this code so that a process prints its information after its child process has exited?

Answer (score 4):

The same modification can do both jobs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t childpid = 0; 
    int i, n;

    if (argc != 2)
    {   /* check for valid number of command-line arguments */ 
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s processes\n", argv[0]);
        return 1; 
    } 
    n = atoi(argv[1]);  
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((childpid = fork()) <= 0)
            break;
    }

    int corpse;
    int status;

    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
               (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "i:%d  process ID:%ld  parent ID:%ld  child ID:%ld\n",
            i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid(), (long)childpid);
    return 0; 
}
```

When a child process executes `wait()`, it immediately fails since there are no grandchildren to be waited for.  Therefore, the child prints its output after "its children" (all zero of them) have exited.

When the parent process executes the `wait()` loop, it reports on each child as the information is made available, and prints its own information afterwards.

You've got more than one child in general, so the second question is a bit ambiguous.  However, if you want it to wait for one child (and you don't care which), then remove the loop from around the `wait()`.  If you care which child, use `waitpid()` instead of just `wait()`.

You can make the output more interesting by returning `i` or a number calculated from `i` in the child processes.  Note that before the forking loop runs from `1` rather than `0`, so if you specify `4` on the command line, you get 3 child processes plus the original parent process.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly why, but a lot depends on scheduling, and the number of cores on the machine, and this sort of thing. One other possibility is that you didn't recompile successfully — unlikely, but funnier things have happened. Each child will report its data; the only question is the order in which they'll report, and whether the command line prompt has already appeared (if you run it from a shell; if you run it in a GUI, you'll probably simply see the lines appear — and maybe disappear).